# java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, list, collections, long-integer

> Blockquote

I am trying to Iterate List of Long objects and setting each value into long variable.But i am getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException :: cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

How can I get solve this issue?

```
List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long>();
listLong = SampleService.sampleList();

for(int i=0;i<listLong.size();i++){
    long sampleId = listLong.get(i).longValue();
}
```

`

```
public List<Long> sampleList() throws Exception{

    LOGGER.info("start of sampleList method ");
    List<Long> sampList = null;
    final MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

    final SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withProcedureName("SAMPLE_TERM");
    simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("SAMPLE_CURSER",
            OracleTypes.CURSOR, new SampleRowMapper()));

    final Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(params);

    sampList = (List<Long>) out.get("SAMPLE_CURSER");
    LOGGER.debug("List  :: "+sampList .size());

    return sampList ;

}
```

> 

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sample cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
        at com.sample.cronTask(sample.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: i was just calling that service which returns list of Long objects      List<Long> sampleList()

Comment: Uhm your code does not seem right `kycIdList` ??? Where is this declared at? What is it? Do you have this class and the methods it has?

Comment: @DummyData, show us the signature of the `SampleService.sampleList()` method

Comment: and the full stack trace

Comment: You should not need to call `Long.longValue()`, apart from seeing why your having this issue, why not let Java Autounbox for you?

Comment: Seems that `SampleService.sampleList()` returns list that contains not a Long object. Try         `List tempList = SampleService.sampleList();
        
        for (Object el : tempList) {
            System.out.println(el.getClass().getName());
        }` to print what type it actually contains.

Comment: sampleList() method returns list<Long> only

Comment: What's code of your SampleRowMapper? Seems, that the error is there... And give the full stacktrace and show real code of the line, where the exception is?

Comment: i was getting exception in this line long sampleId = listLong.get(i).longValue();

Comment: @DummyData; give us entire stacktrace or some more part of it.

Comment: 49 line reffers to listLong = SampleService.sampleList();

Answer (score 0):

Most Probably the scenario in code is like this:

```
    class `your_com.sample`{ 
    long a;..... 
    getA(); .--getters & setters
   setA();
}
```

now, You need to replace all `list<Long>` with `list<your_com.sample>` declarations at all places in code.

Also, your Map declarations would be like this:

```
final Map<String, your_com.sample> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(params);
```

Once you do all those replacements, then for return of `your_com.sample` you need to do below:

```
List<your_com.sample> listLong = new ArrayList<your_com.sample>();
listLong = SampleService.sampleList();

for(int i=0;i<listLong.size();i++){
    long sampleId = listLong.get(i).getA();
}
```

Comment: `execute` returns `Map<String, Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Consider your method SampleService.sampleList(). It returns something which is not of type Long.

```
private static List<Long> sampleList(){
    long[] longs = new long[]{1L};
    longs[0]=10000;
    List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<Long> ();
    for (long item : longs)
        myList.add(item);
    return myList;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> listLong = new ArrayList<Long> ();
        listLong=sampleList();
        
        System.out.println(" ArrayList Elements");
        
        for(int i=0;i<listLong.size();i++){
            long sampleId = listLong.get(i).longValue();
            System.out.println(sampleId);
    }
```

This might be helpful.

**Result:**

ArrayList Elements
10000